# Django Template Form

Tags: python, django

This is how my form input field looks like!

```
<td>Email:</td>
<td>{{ form.email }}</td>
```

It's giving Email: & then input field as usual.

In < input /> fields we have placeholder="..." which shows up in the input. But in my case how can I pre-populate email inside input as a placeholders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do this by writing your HTML manually, for example

```
<input type="text" id="id_email" name="email" placeholder="{{placeholder_email_here}}"/>
```

Or use a django packge to help, for example [django-widget-tweaks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks)

```
{% render_field form.email placeholder="{{placeholder_email_here}}" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put placeholders in attributes for the widget you're using in your e-mail field:

```
email_field = forms.EmailField(
    label='Email',
    widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': '...'})
)
```

If you want to pre-populate actual values, you'll want to set those values in the `initial` value of your form.

Some links: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values